# No value given for one or more required parameters reader vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am getting the above error message when running the following bit of code on a form

```
 Dim SqlString As String = "select [containmentid],[incidentid],[containmentdate],[containment] from [containment] WHERE [incidentid] = " & lbl_incidentid.Text & ""
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Using command As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                conn.Open()
                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                Try
                    If reader.Read() Then
                        Button1.Visible = False
                    Else
                        Button1.Visible = True
                    End If
                Finally
                    reader.Close()
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

I thought it was because I was missing an apostrophie around the lbl_incidentid part, so if I amend the sql line to read

```
Dim SqlString As String = "select [containmentid],[incidentid],[containmentdate],[containment] from [containment] WHERE [incidentid] = '" & lbl_incidentid.Text & "'"
```

I now get the following error

Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

If I amend the sql line to read a number I know is there such as follows

```
 Dim SqlString As String = "select [containmentid],[incidentid],[containmentdate],[containment] from [containment] WHERE [incidentid] = 622"
```

It works fine, I am bound to be missing something glaringly obvious but I just cant see it. Can anyone tell me why my code is wrong?

Comment: Not an postrophe is missing but sql parameters

Comment: You'd only need apostrophes if incidentid is a string type in the database (e.g. varchar, nvarchar). If it's a numeric type such as int then no apostrophe is needed. Anyway, Have you checked that `lbl_incidentid.Text` actually contains a valid value?  P.S. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should use parameterised queries, as per Tim's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to remove the apostrophes around the integer. However, do not try to fix this. Instead always use sql-parameters. For example to prevent sql-injection:

```
Dim SqlString As String = "select [containmentid],[incidentid],[containmentdate],[containment] from [containment] WHERE [incidentid] = @incidentid"
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
    Using command As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
        ' *** That's all you need to safeguard your code: ***
        command.Parameters.Add("@incidentid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(lbl_incidentid.Text)
        Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
            conn.Open()
            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Try
                If reader.Read() Then
                    Button1.Visible = False
                Else
                    Button1.Visible = True
                End If
            Finally
                reader.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Hi Tim Thanks for the response, I'll admit I'm a newbie at this and I am mostly fudging my way through building this project. I actually had no idea you could use parametrics for this.

Comment: However, command.Parameters.Add("@incidentid", OleDbType.Int) returns the error Error  'Int' is not a member of 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType'.

Comment: @Boneyt: well, you need to check if it works for you. Syntax depends on database. Maybe yours doesn't support named parameters

Comment: thanks @Tim Schmelter, any ideas how to combat Conversion from string "label" to type 'Integer' is not valid?

Comment: @Boneyt: so `lbl_incidentid.Text` contains the string `label` and you want to use this as parameter for the `incidentid`? That doesn't sound like a valid value for `incidentid`. What is the type of that column in your database? If it's `varchar`(string) use `OleDbType.VarChar` and remove the `CInt`, you can assign `lbl_incidentid.Text` directly.

Comment: by default the label reads the word label but on form load will change to the incidentid, so it looks like this is trying to complete the task above before its performing the task of changing the label text. I will investigate, thankyou very much for your help